# Algorithm to find resource-free slot

Tags: algorithm, project-management

I am designing a project management app for a factory. The app is expected to produce draft project plans. To schedule a task, the app should check three conditions:

1. task dependency - do not start before,
2. machine availability, and
3. shift work hours

I keep track of machine engagement in `machine_allocations` table:

```
machine_allocations
+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+
| machine_id | operation_id | start_timestamp | end_timestamp |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Shift hours follow a pattern.

Now, to find the earliest possible date-time for an operation I am thinking of a function:

```
function earliest_slot($machine_id, $for_duration, $no_sooner_than) {
   // pseudo code
   1. get records for the machine in question for after $no_sooner_than 
   2. put start and end timestamps into $unavailable array
   3. add non-working times as new elements to the array
   4. in a loop find timeslots which are not in the array
   5. if a timeslot is found which is equal to or bigger than $for_duration, return that
}
```

My question is, is this a good approach? Are there simpler ways to do this?

Comment: 1+ from me for quite literally being the first on-topic question I've ever seen in the [project-management] tag that's actually using the tag properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the earliest date-time for one operation at a time may not give you the best result. Consider the example where operation A uses machine 1 for a long time, operation B uses machine 1 for a short time and operation C uses machine 2 for a short time, but operation C must be done after B.

In this case, it is better to schedule B before A on machine 1, but your approach would not achieve this. Of course, writing and using software to manage this would be more difficult than what you have suggested, so you need to decide whether the benefit is worth the extra effort.

Have a look at [Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28production_processes%29), [Job Shop Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Shop_Scheduling) and [Scheduling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_algorithm).

First you need to think about what sort of information you can collect about tasks (such as dependencies, priorities, deadlines) and then decide how best to put it together.

You may find that an approach like you propose is good enough in your case. My addition to your proposed algorithm would be to sort the list of existing machine operations to make searching through them faster, that is you can stop as soon as you find a time where your operation fits because it's guaranteed to be the earliest time.

A relatively simple extension would be a priority system that allows you to bump lower-priority tasks forward (which may require the adjustment of their dependencies as well), but more complicated algorithms would consider multiple tasks at once and try to optimise the outcome. In the end it comes down to what's appropriate for your specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for the good advise. I am aware the plan so produced would not be optimal, and that is why I am calling it a `draft plan`. I am not promising the customer it would free them from the need to adjust the schedules by hand. So I am approaching it in a way to keep the complexity in check. So, for the *limited utility value* I am planning to offer, do you find the algorithm is the simplest it can be?

Comment: I think the algorithm is *simple enough* for it not to matter. Don't waste time looking for the simplest solution if you have a simple solution, especially if your requirements may change...

Answer (score 0):

That depends when You want to plan work. If before starting work of machines then mayby a Branch&Bound algorithm, or something like it (mayby dynamic programming). If work have to planned when machines are working and You can not tell what jobs would be performed then for optimal solution You can not count (well I can't think about it). Mayby put next jobs on machine with smalles max time? Mayby a dynamic version of Ford-Bellmas alg (if you have couple layers of production). Hard to say.
I would do couple of approches and determine witch are best. The You can write an article about this :)

Comment: I think you didn't read the question correctly. The question is quite specific – how to best implement the `earliest_slot` function.

Comment: @neosatan thanks. Each task is to be planed at the first possible time; and *possible* here means we should satisfy the three conditions: (i) do not eat the ice-cream before you buy it, (ii) the machine we need should be free for the duration of the task, (iii) do not set the task to a non-working time.

Comment: @svick I read it correctly, but when it goes to job sheulding all information you can get are very important. Question was in my opinion not accurate so I put here a general answer. Artelius put a very good answer, I wanted to get more info.